# How to create and download a csv file from perl script

Tags: csv, perl, cgi

I can create a CSV file easily enough:

```
use Text::CSV_XS;
my $filename = "export.csv";
my $fh;
my $csv = Text::CSV_XS->new ({ binary => 1 });
$csv->eol ("\r\n");

my @rows = ();
push @rows, ['Col1','Col2','Col3'];
push @rows, ['a', 'b', 'c'];
push @rows, ['d', 'e', 'f'];

open $fh, ">:encoding(utf8)", $filename or die "$filename: $!";
$csv->print ($fh, $_) for @rows;
close $fh or die "$filename: $!";
```

However if I try to run this same code as a CGI script through a web browser the downloaded csv file is blank.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use CGI;
use Text::CSV_XS;

my $filename = "export.csv";
print "Content-Type:application/x-download\n";
print "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename\n";
print "\n";

my $fh;
my $csv = Text::CSV_XS->new ({ binary => 1 });
# Specify newline as CR+LF
$csv->eol ("\r\n");

my @rows = ();
push @rows, ['Col1','Col2','Col3'];
push @rows, ['a', 'b', 'c'];
push @rows, ['d', 'e', 'f'];

open $fh, ">:encoding(utf8)", $filename or die "$filename: $!";
$csv->print ($fh, $_) for @rows;
close $fh or die "$filename: $!";
```

This code is trying to write the file to disk. The file written does not appear to be the same file downloaded. I don't want a file written to disk. Is there any way to create this file in memory then set headers for download?

Thank you in advance for any help you can provide.

Comment: I had to look up "Content-Disposition: attachment", I'd never heard of it before.  Sounds like it's still an RFC, not official, maybe not implemented well everywhere?  What about setting your Content-Type to whatever a CSV file should be, and just printing the CSV output to the console (browser), instead of to a file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see from the two headers that you print, in a CGI program any data that you want sent back to the client (e.g. a browser) should be just printed to `STDOUT`.

So I think your fix is as simple as changing:

```
$csv->print ($fh, $_) for @rows;
```

to print to `STDOUT` instead:

```
$csv->print (STDOUT, $_) for @rows;
```

You can also remove any code that is involved in handling the file that you now no longer use.

Comment: Thank you Dave. That changed worked. As is usually the case, it was something simple that I overlooked.